# MDX with IIF parameter

Tags: mdx, ssrs-2012

I'm tyring to discern an amount based on a parameter.  I currently have the @ClientType defaulted to 'C'.

```
WITH 
MEMBER
[Measures].[Amount] AS
   IIF(
     @ClientType ='C',
       [Measures].[Total Client Amount] , 
      -[Measures].[Total Client Amount]
   )
```

Regardless of changing the @ClientType I'm still only returning the FALSE.

Comment: this depends on the rest of your script. Please show us the rest. Did you try just changing the `'C'` to a `"C"`, although this is just a shot in the dark as I've not played with `SSRS` parameters against olap.

Comment: could be more on the `ssrs` side - what type is the parameter  `@ClientType` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding in these two measures inspect their values:

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Measures].[ClntTypParam] AS @ClientType
MEMBER [Measures].[ClntTypParamC] AS 
  IIF (
    @ClientType = "c"
   ,"equalToC"
   ,"notC"
  )
```

Comment: Thanks.  That makes sense to me to able to evaluate.  I'm new to mdx and getting my bearings straight.  Will check first thing in the morning and reply.

Comment: @mrbungle `mdx`: welcome to the longest learning curve in BI !

Comment: @mrbungle did this answer solve your question or did you find an alternative approach?